# Server to client communication gRpc

Tags: c, http, go, websocket, grpc

i'm having a little trouble trying to come to a solution and was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction.

I am implementing a system in which multiple clients are communicating with a server using gRpc.
The service is written in golang and the clients are written in C.

I am trying to work out how to best handle communicating from the server to the client.

The options which i have considered so far are:

1. **Setup a server on each client**

   - Considering there may be multiple clients operating from one external ip i'm not sure if it's possible to create a client listening to a combination of public ip, local ip and port ?
2. **Use** [bi-directional streaming](https://grpc.io/docs/guides/concepts.html#bidirectional-streaming-rpc)

   - This seems like the wrong application of the above, will you have to spawn a new process just to hold open a connection ?
3. **Open a websocket alongside the gRpc service**

   - I feel like this is not the right solution but seems to be the easiest out of the 3

I am also not completely confident as to the required work to implement each of the above in C as it seems alot of helper functionality isn't included in C

## Update:

So i have implemented a solution using a go client + server. Making use of the bi-directional rpc stream,

### Server

- Create a chan for each client that connects and store it in a map on the service
- Inside the stream method run a for

  - Check the chan for any messages and call stream.sen
  - Remove the client chan if stream.Context().Err()

### Client

- Create a channel for the messages coming back from the stream method
- Start a goroutine calling stream.Recv on the stream service

Is this a reasonable approach to keep a connection open to the connected clients?

Answer (score 0):

About your choices:

1. Setup a server on each client

I don't know you use case, but normally you can not require or guarantee that users can open listeners. The normal way is the client connect to the server and keep a channel opened.

2. Use bi-directional streaming

`gRPC` can be used as streaming to receive Server Side Events(SSE). So this can be a good choice.
https://docs.servicestack.net/server-events-grpc#streamserverevents

> Is this a reasonable approach to keep a connection open to the connected clients?

I can't see anything wrong with this approach.

3. Open a websocket alongside the gRpc service

Until now, I know no better solution to communicate events via http protocol other than WebSocket. It's very easy to implement, has a mature API based on events, supports text and binary data. From the development perspective you just need to worry about specific reverse proxy rules to `ws` or `wss` protocols.